# ARM generic timer simulation

Tags: arm

I need to simulate ARMv8 generic timers with TRACE32, so I have created a linux kernel for ARMv8 with buildroot and QEMU 2.9.0 in a linux x86 host(UBUNTU 16.04).
But I can't find where the generic timers was declared.
anyone can help me please?